# Java - Convert string to ISO 8601 date format error Joda-Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to convert the date entered by my app user as String to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), so I am using the following code but I get error:

```
String oldDate = "05/05/2013";
DateTime oldD = DateTime.parse(oldDate);
DateTimeFormatter OldDFmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
String str = OldDFmt.print(oldD);
System.out.println(str);
```

but I am always getting error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "05/05/2013" is
>   malformed at "/05/2013"

Can someone please help and tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: When reading exceptions like that, the hint is usually in the message.  There was a problem parsing "/05/2013", which is a bit of your oldDate variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can someone please help and tell me what I am doing wrong here?

The error occurs here.

```
DateTime oldD = DateTime.parse(oldDate);
```

The `DateTime.parse(String)` method parses your `String` argument using a `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`.

The [format must be of the form](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser%28%29)

```
 datetime          = time | date-opt-time
 time              = 'T' time-element [offset]
 date-opt-time     = date-element ['T' [time-element] [offset]]
 date-element      = std-date-element | ord-date-element | week-date-element
 std-date-element  = yyyy ['-' MM ['-' dd]]
 ord-date-element  = yyyy ['-' DDD]
 week-date-element = xxxx '-W' ww ['-' e]
 time-element      = HH [minute-element] | [fraction]
 minute-element    = ':' mm [second-element] | [fraction]
 second-element    = ':' ss [fraction]
 fraction          = ('.' | ',') digit+
 offset            = 'Z' | (('+' | '-') HH [':' mm [':' ss [('.' | ',') SSS]]])
```

which yours

```
String oldDate = "05/05/2013";
```

isn't.

You'll need to parse your `String` date with a parser with a corresponding format, like what [Paul Hicks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21505341/438154) is suggesting. You can then format the created `DateTime` into the ISO standard format.

Comment: Well, what I am trying to do is convert this strong which is not in ISO 8601 format to ISO 8601 format, and that's why I used .dateTime method, make sense? If my string is already in ISO 8601 format, why will I care to convert it?

Comment: @MChan A `String` does not have an ISO 8601 format, a date does. You can parse a `DateTime` from a `String` and format that `DateTime` into the ISO format. The step of parsing into a `DateTime` object will have to use some other format that is not ISO 8601.

Comment: @MChan I misread your question. Take a look at [Paul's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21505341/438154) answer and my edit.

Comment: That's a big edit :)  I'd already upvoted, I think it's all sorted now.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've read both your answer and Paul answer, I am quite confused now. Sequence of code is as follows, the user enters date in format MM/dd/yyyy which I have in String oldDate, now if I used DateTimeFormat I won't get the date as ISOFormat using Joda time, I mean I have to change all the code to use regular Java Date class....correct? All I am trying to do here is take the user input (which is a date entered in format MM/dd/yyyy and convert it to a ISO 8601 format using Joda time

Comment: @MChan You get the date in the `MM/dd/yyyy` format. You need to parse it in that format to create a `DateTime` object. Then you can format the generated `DateTime` with the ISO format.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ah ok sorry my mistake, I got confused. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes.  Contrary to Sotirios' comment earlier, DateTimes *don't* have a format, they're just a point in time.  Only the output formatter needs to know about the ISO date format.

Answer (score 4):

The formatter you're using to parse the string `DateTime.parse(oldDate)` is the default one: according to the javadocs, `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`.  You want a parsing `DateTimeFormatter` that knows about your string format `dd/mm/yyyy`.  I don't use joda-time, but I think you want this:

```
DateTimeFormatter stringParser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The rest of the code looks ok.